# Inmobi integration issue for iOS (using unity for generating project)

Tags: inmobi

I have imported the latest inmobi unity package 10.0.1 properly. On building the project for iOS, pod for inmobi sdk is not getting added into pod file(all my other sdks are added into pod file properly)

I have gone through the documentation and nothing more than importing the package is given for unity.

Comment: why isn't inmobisdk dependency not getting added into podfile when others are?